# How do i solve the index error in the function

Tags: python, algorithm, index-error

I've made a simple program. Which it deletes a few different substrings among 2 strings.

Like `Delete("hello","helloworld")` -> `"hello"`.
Then, I got the following error:

> IndexError: pop from empty list

```
def Delete(s,t):
    list_t=list(t)
    list_s=list(s)
    while list_t!=list_s:
        list_t.pop()
        #list_t.pop()
    return "".join(list_t)
print(Delete("hello","helloworld"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you call `pop` twice for each `while` iteration. So after the third iteration you will have:

```
list_t -> ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']
list_s -> ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

This causes an infinite loop, which stops by an error of you trying to `pop` element from an empty list. Remove one of the `pop` and the problem is solved:

```
def Delete(s,t):
    list_t=list(t)
    list_s=list(s)
    while list_t!=list_s:
        list_t.pop()
        #list_t.pop()
    return "".join(list_t)
print(Delete("hello","helloworld"))
```